# Problem: Property 'enableBulkApi' not valid in version 30.0

Tags: deployment, sandbox, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am having an issue with deploying from developer org to sandBox with using force.com IDE, **"Problem: Property 'enableBulkApi' not valid in version 30.0"**
 - Anyone know how to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: Wasn't bulk api introduced in version 33? That may be the reason why it doesn't work in earlier api version

Answer (score 2):

Manually edit the version at the end of your package.xml to change it from 30.0 to 33.0:

```
    ...
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

and try the deploy again.

This value defaults to the version of the IDE but can be changed.

(There is a new version of the Force.com IDE that probably does set this value automatically to 33.0 - see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE.)